# iPhone 4S - UnAuthorized Access Exception

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin

This is a question I am sure Xcode developers could also answer. I have a screenshot of my code below in Xamarin.

Why am I getting an Unauthorized access exception? I should be able to write to the documents folder right?

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
        //var documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // iOS 7 and earlier
        var documentsFolder = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
        var fileNameAndPath = Path.Combine (documentsFolder, "verses.xml");


        if(!File.Exists(documentsFolder)){

            Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsFolder);

            if(!File.Exists(fileNameAndPath)){

                //File.SetAttributes(fileNameAndPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
                File.Create(fileNameAndPath);
                //Throws exception here.

            }

        }
```

And ERRORs:

Access to the path "/var/mobile/Applications/1F95D694-BBA5-4FB3-AE6C-0C2CDD9DEDD8/comexample.app/verses.xml" is denied

Access to the path '/private/var/mobile/Applications/1F95D694-BBA5-4FB3-AE6C-0C2CDD9DEDD8/Documents/verses.xml' is denied.

I have tried both paths and I get access denied.

Answer (score 2):

The BundlePath is not a writable area for iOS applications.

From the Xamarin notes at http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/

The following snippet will create a file into the writable documents area.

```
var documents =
  Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); // iOS 7 and earlier
var filename = Path.Combine (documents, "Write.txt");
File.WriteAllText(filename, "Write this text into a file");
```

There's a note on the page for iOS 8 that a change is required to get the documents folder

```
var documents = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrls (NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, 
  NSSearchPathDomain.User) [0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on iOS 8, the documents directory isn't connected to the bundle path.  Use the function `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains()` (or `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:`) to find the documents directory.

Comment: I am   running iOS 7.1.2

Comment: Regardless of which version of iOS you're running, you should be using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`. I don't know if it has ever been advisable to build the documents path without this function. (Available since iOS 2.0)

Comment: I'd try the function anyway.  Even if it still gives you a problem, at least you'll be using a recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it should be a Directory.Exists() where you check if the directory exists:

`if(!File.Exists(documentsFolder)){`